# Prove asymptotic relationship using the limit method

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

Prove that $$n\log(n) = o(n^{3/2})$$ using the limit method`

Note that log is in base 2.

I've missed a few classes due to illness and am trying to catch up. From the notes, I see that I can compute the following:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n\log(n)}{n^{3/2}} = 0$$

But now what? Has it been proved? It makes sense that $n^{3/2}$ bounds $n\log(n)$ however, let's also note that this is small-oh not big-oh. Am I finished the proof?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: "makes sense" probably won't get you marks in your exam. "bounds" is not sufficient either.

Comment: What should I say then?

Comment: Explain convincingly to someone for whom it doesn't "make sense" why the limit is zero. For example, use a particular theorem you learned in class.

Comment: What theorem is this? It appears that this a definition of little-oh; for example, http://oeis.org/wiki/Asymptotic_notations#Little_o_notation.

Comment: Hi - I don't think we've learned that theorem. If you could tell me, that would be great; I feel like I'm missing on something

Comment: I will ask my professor then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have finished the proof.

$g(n) = o(f(n))$ is defined to mean $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)} = 0$

Comment: Good thanks. And if it was big-oh, then if the limit approached any constant then it would be true as well right?

Comment: @user1008537 Yes, by definition, $g(n) = O(f(n))$ means $\exists M>0$ such that $|\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}| < M$ for any $n$